# How to write regular expression to extract years

Tags: regex, python-3.x, information-extraction

How can we write regular expression to extract years in texts, years may come in the following forms

```
Case 1:
1970 - 1980 --> 1970, 1980
January 1920 - Feb 1930 --> 1920, 1930
May 1920 to September 1930 --> 1920, 1930
Case 2:
July 1945 --> 1945
```

Writing regular expression for `Case 1` is easy but how can I tackle `Case 2` along with it

```
\d{4} \s? (?: [^a-zA-Z0-9] | to) \s? \w+? \d{4}
```

Comment: Can you just use `\b\d{4}\b`?

Comment: `Writing regular expression for Case 1 is easy` I'd back up a bit. Your regex doesn't match anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regex**: [`.*?([0-9]{4})(?:.*?([0-9]{4}))?`](https://regex101.com/r/dWTulg/2) or `.*?(\d{4})(?:.*?(\d{4}))?`

Details:

- `()` Capturing group
- `(?:)` Non capturing group
- `{n}` Matches exactly `n` times
- `.*?` Matches any char between zero and unlimited times (lazy)

**Python code**:

```
def Years(text):
        return re.findall(r'.*?([0-9]{4})(?:.*?([0-9]{4}))?', text)

print(Years('January 1920 - Feb 1930'))
```

Output:

```
[('1920', '1930')]
```

Answer (score 2):

for your requirement, just match all 4 digit numbers

```python
import re
s = '''1970 - 1980
January 1920 - Feb 1930
May 1920 to September 1930
July 1945'''

p = re.compile(r'\b\d{4}\b')

s = s.splitlines()
for x in s:
    result = p.findall(x) 
    print(result)
```

output

```python
['1970', '1980']
['1920', '1930']
['1920', '1930']
['1945']
```